# can HTML play streaming video from URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-player

I have this URL:
http://31.220.1.190:8080/WuYC3qhd9/65udrOt48Y/197939

I got it from a m3u file.This url runs Ok with VLC media player.
Is it possible to play this URL by Html or Javascript? Or is it possible to play a m3u file by Html or Javascript?
Could somebody point me to the right direction?
Desperately looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: need help......

Answer (score 2):

**m3u** is a format for multimedia playlist, rather than a media file itself.

Something like this will play it in Internet Explorer.

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="46">
    <param name="fileName" value="http://31.220.1.190:8080/WuYC3qhd9/65udrOt48Y/197939"> 
    <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
    <param name="autoStart" value="true">
    <param name="showControls" value="true">
    <param name="Volume" value="-300">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://31.220.1.190:8080/WuYC3qhd9/65udrOt48Y/197939" name="MediaPlayer1" width=280 height=46 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300>
</OBJECT>
```

Comment: what if I have a .mp4 or .mkv video?